# Why is os.path.exists('~') False?

Tags: python

(It seems this would be a duplicate, but I cannot find. Please mark if you find it!)

I'm just curious, why does `os.path.exists('~')` return `False`? Clearly, my home folder does exist.

Comment: Because Python doesn't parse `~` as the home folder. Use `os.path.expanduser()` to convert it to an actual pathname.

Comment: From the top of the documentation for the os.path module: `Unlike a unix shell, Python does not do any automatic path expansions. Functions such as expanduser() and expandvars() can be invoked explicitly when an application desires shell-like path expansion. (See also the glob module.)`

Comment: @Barmar - so: `os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~'))` ?

Comment: RufusVS: Jeez, just ***try it*** yourself.